# Regex grouping in Java

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, package

I'm looking to clean everything but the Class name off of a fully qualified Class name. So, I may have something like.....

```
"class gqlMain.Node"
```

... and I'd like to end up with....

```
"Node"
```

...I'm pretty sure my pattern...

```
"*.[\\.][^\\.]*"
```

..is correct, and when if simply run it as above and test with...

```
myMatcherObject.matches()
```

...it always returns true, but when I attempt to add groupings, like...

```
"(.*[\\.])([^\\.]*)"
```

...I always get a no match found error. Not sure what's going on.

ADDED:

Thanks for the quick responses, guys. Yeah, I really don't get this. My exact code is....

```
public String toString() {
    Pattern packagePatt = Pattern.compile("(.*[\\.])([^\\.]*)");
    // 
    System.out.println(this.compClass.getName().toString());

    Matcher packageMatch = packagePatt.matcher(this.compClass.getName().toString());

    //
    System.out.println(packageMatch.group(2));
    return packageMatch.group(2);
}
```

The first print statement produces a String like "gqlMain.Node", for example (I know the toString() is redundant, I added it out of exasperation). The second print statement produces an error, as would the return statement. With a debugger I can see that the groups List for the Matcher object remains empty at every index. But if I insert a...

```
if (packageMatcher.matches()) {
    // print true
}
```

... I always get 'true'. This really makes no sense.

Comment: "*.[\\.][^\\.]*" and "(.*[\\.])([^\\.]*)" are not the same, although I would have thought the second one would be the one to work. Note the "*." at the beginning of the first regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend to scan for the identifiers in that way (but I believe you wanted not to over-engineer), and you probably will like the following solution that is more strict for scanning the identifiers in general (however, speaking frankly, I don't believe I'm scanning for an identifier in the most correct way too). Additionally, it can scan for several fully/partially qualified identifiers within a single string, but it completely ignores non-qualified one (e.g. `class` is ambiguous).

```java
package stackoverflow;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import static java.lang.System.out;
import static java.util.regex.Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE;
import static java.util.regex.Pattern.compile;

public final class Q11554180 {

    private Q11554180() {
    }

    //
    // (3) The same as item (1) however we're       ------------------------------------------------+
    //     capturing the group to get the class                                                     |
    //     name only                                                                                |
    // (2) At least one package name is required    ---------------------------------+              |
    // (1) We're searching valid package names only -----------------+               |              |
    //     and we do not need to capture it ?:                       |               |              |
    //                                              +----------------+--------------+|+-------------+-------------+
    //                                              |                               |||                           |
    private static final Pattern pattern = compile("(?:[\\p{Alpha}_][\\p{Alnum}_]*\\.)+([\\p{Alpha}_][\\p{Alnum}_]*)", CASE_INSENSITIVE);

    private static void find(CharSequence s) {
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
        while ( matcher.find() ) {
            out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        find("class gqlMain.Node; class gqlMain.p1.NodeA");
        find("class gqlMain.p1.p11.NodeB");
        find("class gqlMain.p1.p11.p111.NodeC");
        find(Q11554180.class.getCanonicalName());
    }

}
```

The code above will produce the following output:

```
Node
NodeA
NodeB
NodeC
Q11554180
```

Answer (score 1):

The following program reported "true":

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;




public class so {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*[\\.])([^\\.]*)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher("class gqlMain.Node");
        System.out.println(m.matches());
        System.out.println(m.group(0));
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
        System.out.println(m.group(2));

    }

}
```

The full output is:

```
true
class gqlMain.Node
class gqlMain.
Node
```

Comment: I agree with teambob. However, I feel the `\\ ` should not be there.

Comment: The \\ is fine but is unnecessary, I was trying to match @MassStrike's code as closely as possible. First we match any character ".*. Then we match any character except a literal period / full-stop - normally you would need to escape the full-stop but it is not necessary inside a character specification. Then the second group matches any character except a literal full-stop. Actually if we cut out all the unnecessary characters we have "(.*\\.)([^.]*)" or "(.*[.])([^.]*)" - which works exactly the same.